# paypal express - checkout a guest

Tags: php, paypal

Does anyone know a way to change the wording on the second payment option on the paypal express checkout to something more specific, ie change 'checkout as guest' to something like 'pay with card' or 'pay using debit/credit card'?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change that. It is the default behavior for the new express checkout pages.